# How to fix problem with iterating through list if times using iterator?

Tags: c++

Debugger sais there is an incompatible iterator.
How i can solve this.
What can cause the problem.
Here is my main code

```
for (std::list<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>>
::iterator it = road.get_times().begin()
;it!= road.get_times().end();it++,z++) //error incompatible iterator
            {
                *road::file << "Samochod z drogi " << road.get_lane_number() << " pojechal ";
                switch (road.get_direction())
                {
                case'S':
                    *road::file << "prosto" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case'L':
                    *road::file << "w lewo" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case'R':
                    *road::file << "w prawo" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                *road::file << "Jego czas stania w kolejce wyniosl ";
                avarage_time += it->count() / 1000;
                *road::file << round(it->count() / 1000) << std::endl;
                }
```

function road.get_times ()

```
   std::list< std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>> get_times()
    {
    return times;
    }
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Debug assertion failed

Expression: list iterators incompatible

Comment: it is from chrono library it says that actual time has to be in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_times` returns by value, which means that every time you call it you get a new `list` object. This is what happens in your `for` loop. You call it 2 times and you get two objects. You can't compare iterators from two different objects. To fix this create one object by calling `get_times` just once:

```
auto times = road.get_times();

for (auto it = times.begin(); it != times.end(); ++it, z++)
    //...
```

You also might want to pause and consider if returning by value is the right approach. I can't answer that for you since I don't know what `times` is and what is the structure of your program.

Comment: yeah this was so simple thank you very much it was so obvious ehh

Comment: @MaciejKról if this solved your problem you should mark the answer as accepted.